# Object detection using VGG16 in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, vgg-net

I have a VGG16 pretrained model which I have converted already to tf-lite. Now I want to deploy this model in Android Studio to extract feature vectors from all my **gallery images**. For that, how should I proceed starting from accessing all my images ?